# How to hide a widget created by QtDesigner "design" mode programmatically?

Tags: qt, qt5, qt-designer

I want to know how to create a QLabel in QtCreator Design mode that is hidden by default?
In the properties list in the right hand side panel , there's not any option regarding `visibility` and also adding `label->hide()` to `setupUi` function (after compiling ui file and adding to the project headers) makes no difference.

Comment: it can not.....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Designer doesn't expose the `visible` property.  You could hand-edit the UI file, but that will be overwritten next time you edit in Designer.  It's best to leave it visible in Designer, and just write a line of code after you call `setupUi()` to hide the widget you don't want to be initially shown.